# How to turn a nested array in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

How can I retrieve the nested arrays with map?
I want to pass the records to be registered to Route53 from local.

example

```
locals {

  cname = {
    "bbb.example.io" = {
      records = ["example"]
    }
    "aaa.example.io" = {
      records = [
        "example1",
        "example2",
        "example3"
      ]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "cname" {
  for_each = local.cname
  name     = each.key
  records  = [] ←Problem areas
  ttl      = 300
  type     = "CNAME"
  zone_id  = aws_route53_zone.example.zone_id
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the way you've set up the `for_each` in this example, `each.value` in that block will be the corresponding object from your `local.cname` map, so you can access the `records` attribute of that object in the usual way:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "cname" {
  for_each = local.cname
  name     = each.key
  records  = each.value.records
  ttl      = 300
  type     = "CNAME"
  zone_id  = aws_route53_zone.example.zone_id
}
```

Comment: thanks comment!!
I tried to do it that way, but when I looked closely at my code, I found that I put the same values in the array and it didn't work the way I expected.